# Why is a 15 stage binary counter/divider so cumbersome?

Tags: clock, flipflop, counter, binary, frequency-divider

There seem to be many ways to take a 32.768kHz signal and turn it into 1Hz.

- I can use a CD4060, but still have to add a flip-flop... so 2 "large" chips with excess (potentially) unused functions there. Sure the other 4060 outputs *could* come in handy, and I *might* find a use for the other flip-flop on board, but still a *lot* of real estate for a pile of maybe with a built-in oscillator likely as accurate as a 555 - negated by a crystal anyhow.
- The "Swiss Army Knife of dividers" - I can use the programmable CD4536, which provides a single output from any stage from 1-24. But again, with chip size *and* "wiring" for programming - a lot of real estate for one function - and again with the on board oscillator.
- The picture of simplicity, Nexperia makes a small 5-pin 14-stage divider. Oh so close. Still need to add a flip-flop, but at least the '4214 is not a 16 lead divider like the '4060.
- Just for fun, I could cascade 8 CD4013s.

There are other counter/dividers that fall very short or way beyond 15 stages as an option. It seems that 15 stages of binary division is not nearly as important as I would suspect.

**So my question is:** With the 32.768 kHz Crystal being so prolific, and the (I would think, common) need to yield "seconds" with clocks and timers, why is there no discrete solution for doing so? Am I missing something?

**P.S.** I know that microcontrollers, GPS RX, RTCs, and other modern devices can provide all the timekeeping function one might need, but with all of the other "archaic" technology still available, I find it hard to believe such a device doesn't/didn't exist.

**Addendum** I seem to have created some confusion with my example, where I was personally looking for a 1Hz signal from what I thought was a "jellybean" frequency. But, it's about the stage count availability, not the frequency yielded. My example is my discovery of a lack of devices with a specific intermediate division capability - regardless of the input frequency - where the output of \$2^{15}\$ (and 16th and 17th) seems to be almost avoided, and that with the exception of one example, an additional device is required to achieve that number.

I already had my 1Hz solution before this question, but got curious and sought out what I thought was the "old way" of achieving this frequency in small, cheap timing products. So, my search was for a 15th stage *readily available* within a single device. Maybe the 32.768k wasn't part of the old way at all. Regardless, it seemed odd that all of the available preset counters/dividers I found that provide select ranges between \$2^0\$ and \$2^{24}\$ seemed to beat around that \$2^{15}\$ bush.

Comment: because now most users of medium scale ICs don't care about size, neither do their makers.

Comment: A tiny CPLD will do it for under a quid. Specialist ICs for small logic functions were replaced by programmable logic. Until then, people were quite accepting of 74HCT4060 and the other options. I don't recall people being as exasperated and frustrated as your excessive bolds and italics sound. (Over-emphasis reads rage-y.)

Comment: Do YOU have an actual application for such a part? I can't think of anything I'd need it for.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you think there's any great demand for 1-Hz square waves anyway. Clocks and wristwatches have the divider built into dedicated chips, as do RTC chips for computers. What sort of application needs a 1-Hz square wave that doesn't also have a microcontroller of some sort in it?

Comment: @TonyM - LOL on the rage-y. It's more of a bewilderment coupled with a lack of sarcasm font (hence the cascaded 4013s bit). I like all of those devices I mentioned - I have them. I just thought it odd that there may have been no solutions predating the more modern options, and wondered if there was some "logical" reason.

Comment: A $1 PIC and a 2 byte counter in memory with a few bytes of code?.? then more for counting up minutes , hours

Comment: Back in the day, there used to be a chip that would take an NTSC colorburst crystal (3.579545 MHz) -- these were much more common than 32.768 kHz crystals at the time -- and divide that down to 60 Hz to drive a standard line-powered clock chip.

Comment: Single chip digital watch (obsolete): http://electronicsusa.com/mm5314nclockchip.html

Comment: @DaveTweed the tragic thing is that NTSC was actually designed to *not* be a multiple of 60 Hz, but the oscillators are so darn cheap that one can live with the small offset to the next integer factor

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Not all that tragic. It isn't at all hard to deal with the 1000/1001 factor in the counter chain.

Comment: Can't be sarcastic to history, old boy. History presents you with a record of what the world of electronics felt it needed and could sell. And it didn't 32.768-to-1 Hz dividers in a dedicated package :-) Out of interest, can you give 5 example applications for it? Not just be 5 uses for counting 1 second, though.

Comment: MM5368 http://www.electro-tech-online.com/attachments/mm5368-pdf.2423

Comment: Regarding your addendum, I don't think you've created confusion. You're basically surprised that it's not easier to create 1Hz from 32.768kHz, but nobody else is because they don't see this as a common requirement and have challenged you to say why it should be.

Comment: @Finbarr Re: 1st comment. I did have an application. In short, I am using a self-imposed set of design constraints to create a binary watch using logic devices as a learning project - with the reward of a nerdy trinket. I need 1Hz for the seconds, of course, and had the impression that the 32.x->1 was the norm. Re: 2nd comment. Actually, that's the confusion. I am surprised by the "hole" in the count availability that I discovered on the search for 1Hz while simultaneously under that original impression that it was (at some point) common.

Comment: @DaveTweed I think your comments pretty much formulate the answer I was looking for before this question. The 32.768kHz crystal was not the common component during times that predate more current time keeping processes. But regardless of input frequency, I am gathering that there is little need for "immediate access" to those 2^15 through 2^17 divisions - while 2^0 to 2^14 and 2^18 to 2^24 are more useful?

Comment: Haha. You are my hero @BruceAbbott ! There was such a thing... and for time keeping to boot. Cool. Still a curious hole in that 15-17 factor though.

Comment: Thinking back, you used to see circuits for generating a 60Hz clock from an NTSC "colorburst" crystal.  They used an MM5369 to divide the 3579545Hz down to 60.  You might find more information about that if you take a look around.  From 60Hz to 1Hz should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that that's not all a counter needs to do.

Since any timer or counter will need to provide BCD counters for the seconds (and minutes and hours, if appropriate), along with display formatting and driving, it makes far more sense for the custom IC to incorporate both the oscillator and the divider chain into the IC, rather than having this as a second, external IC.

What you seem to be asking is why nobody makes a 6-pin IC which takes power, ground, 2 pins for the crystal, and outputs a 1 Hz signal. Well, that's because there isn't much demand for it.

If you want 1 Hz, a much smaller solution is this [ASTMK](http://www.abracon.com/Oscillators/ASTMK.pdf) part, which provides 1 Hz logic-level output in a 2 mm x 1 mm package, which is smaller than a standard 32,768 crystal, which typically will run about 4 mm x 8 mm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's perfect. I actually already had that oscillator in my design, but I don't think I can solder it. My edit might clear up the confusion I caused making my point though.

Comment: You could use a CD4521 with a 4.194304 MHz crystal. The Q22 output is 1Hz.

Answer (score 2):

> with the 32.768 kHz Crystal being so prolific, and the (I would think, common) need to yield "seconds" with clocks and timers, why is there no discrete solution for doing so?

Is that need really all that common? aside from consumer  analog wall clocks, which tend to use cheaper things than DIP packaged ICs, I see none right now – anything that does more than move a seconds hand will simply have a minimal MCU (microwave oven), usually, or even some ASIC (watches, for example).

The use cases for something that *only* divides a slow clock by \$2^{16}\$ kind of seem sparse.

Comment: A look at the supplier I tend to use shows 96 different frequencies of crystal available, and 32.768kHz is the 5th most common, accounting for 80 of the 1462 different parts they list. So yes, it probably justifies the term "common".

Comment: Oh, might have put that ambigously, @Finbarr: Not the 32.768kHz oscillator isn't common – the need for a 1 Hz signal is!

Comment: Fair enough! Even so, I was surprised just how many different parts were listed with the same frequency...

Comment: And as if by magic... Someone else has just asked a question about the [NCP PCF8563 real time clock chip](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF8563.pdf) - which takes a 32.768kHz crystal and contains oscillator, divider, real time clock/calendar, alarms and I2C interface in an 8 pin chip. And you can even program an output pin to generate a 1Hz signal!

Comment: I don't know how common that need would be. It just seemed so, if not currently, at some point. But see my addendum regarding the division factors over the resulting frequency. And @Finbarr. LOL. Learning an RTC will come after I have become comfortable with the logic process and then maybe CPLDs. I know nothing about I2C.

Answer (score 2):

I also needed a 1 Hz clock and wanted to avoid the usual CD4060 / CD4013 / CD4521, and I just found [this AHC divider series from NXP](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/leaflet/Nexperia_AHC_logic_stage_dividers_leaflet_201907.pdf), in particular the [74AHC1G4215](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74AHC1G4215.pdf) that does just that, has a small package and is available for 50ct in qty. 1 from Digikey for example.

I think these are quite recent and weren't available when you posted your original question. For the moment they seem little known, maybe in the future we'll see more of them in DIY clock builds!